# Unit conversion error - Darcy Radius of Well Influence Equation

Tags: civil-engineering, chemical-engineering, mathematics, unit

I'm having a little trouble. I'm trying to convert the answer from imperial to metric but can't seem to get the answer to match. I am using the formula attached (Darcy Radius of Well Influence Equation). [image: Formula]

Unfortunately, replicating the formula in excel has lead me to an inccorect value. In the screenshot below, the top table is me converting my measured values to the original formula units, i get a verified answer. This is correct.
Below that table is where i try to convert the formula into metric units. This has a substantial error of 4.5%.

[image: Excel]

Could someone inform me as to where my unit conversions have gone wrong? Note I have been a bit lazy in my units - lbm is pound mass, and lbf is pound force.

Comment: The equation will probably not work using values of quantities in inconsistent unit system. You may try to put whole quantities into the equation, which (after some units cancel out) may lead to slightly different form of the equation.

Comment: Perform a dimensional analysis on the equation.  Make sure you break everything down to its base units.  (ie. Lbf = Lbm * ft / s^2).  If you find your units don't match when you go to add, or do not match the final units you were expecting, then you are dealing with a constant somewhere that need to be converted accordingly as well.  That or you do not have all your units right.  You did convert all your individual values correctly to metric provided all your indicated imperial units were correct.  Ie.  you indicated ro had units of "f" when I think you meant units of "ft".